# json-content-importer wordpress plugin

Tags: json, wordpress

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":217567
,
         "media":[  

            {  
               "title":"2016-07-23-Illustration.png",
               "sizes":{  
                  "medium":{  
                     "width":"400",
                     "height":"371",
                     "url":"https://d21buns5ku92am.cloudfront.net/32253/273953.png"
                  },

               }
            },
            {  
               "title":"Image1.jpg",
               "sizes":{  
                  "medium":{  
                     "width":"400",
                     "height":"309",
                     "url":"https://d21buns5ku92am.cloudfront.net/9.jpg"
                  }                 
               }
            }
         ],
         "title":"123"
      }
      ]
      }
```

Using `json-content-importer` plugin in WordPress, how can I get the respective URL of images under media ->sizes. Can someone please let me know a sample with which we can extract the URL using `subloop` or `subloop-array`.